# How can call a page on submit using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to create a chat room in php using ajax. Therefore i want to call another page by clicking on submit. I have two pages chat.php and getchat.php. Where am i wrong and how can call the getchat.php . I have try but function is not working. please help me.

**chat.php**

```
    <script>
    function showUser() {

      xmlhttp.open("GET","getchat.php",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
<form onSubmit="showUser(this.value)" method="post">
<label>Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" /><br />
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**getchat.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ajax');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");

$sql="SELECT * FROM chat";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Message</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `I have try but function is not working. please help me` is not adequate enough, what you need to do is say why it isn't working and what errors (if any) are present).

Comment: @Darren no error is present

Comment: Did you enable error reporting? Also, is the table printed out successfully? lack of details.

Comment: I have checked table. Its working properly...

Comment: i can help using jquery. will it work for u??

Comment: @g-newa well I want do it with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did it something like this

chat.php

```
<form id="chat_form" method="post">
<label>Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" /><br />
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#chat_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $("#chat_form").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'getchat.php',
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(info){
                $("#result").html(info);
            },
            error:function(){
                $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
            }   

        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

getchat.php

not changed as yours